# sticky navbar doesn't work with firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I'm quite new to coding and I'm getting mad that my javascript
doesn't work in firefox. I already read all the similar problems on this site, but I still don't get it.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var stickyOffset = $('.header').offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var sticky = $('.header'),
                scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= stickyOffset) sticky.addClass('fixed');
            else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the complete webpage: [www.container.jetzt](http://www.container.jetzt/)
Thanks for helping, Moritz

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? You have to be clear about the problem you are having.

Comment: the header which is supposed to stick ( it does in safari and chrome) is just shaking, it seems that it starts and stops while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Too much stuff to check if the document is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var sticky = $('.header');
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        var stickyOffset = sticky.offset().top;
        $(window).scrollTop() >= stickyOffset ? sticky.addClass('fixed') : sticky.removeClass('fixed');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but now the header doesn't come back down again when I scroll up

Comment: @Moritz doesn't what?

Answer (score 0):

So, I put in a new code

```
$(function(){
    var stickyOffset = $('.header').offset().top;
      $(window).scroll(function(){
        var sticky = $('.header'),
       scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= stickyOffset) sticky.addClass('fixed');
        else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
      });
});
```

it seems to work, but when I first load to page the header is kind of jumpy, when I reload the page it works fine.